# Iterar valores de duas requisições em *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, loop, for

Estou fazendo duas requisições no banco, uma traz os pedidos agrupados apenas para visualização no front, a outra traz todos os valores, essa última preciso mostrar o total de cada pedido junto com a visualização da primeira requisição.

```js
listOrders() {
    this.service.getListOrders().subscribe(data => { // 1º requisição
      console.log(this.list = data['message']);
      for (this.getNumberOrders of this.list) {
        this.getNumberOrder = this.getNumberOrders['order_number'];
        console.log(this.getNumberOrder);
        this.service.getListOrdersNumber(this.getNumberOrder).subscribe(data => { // 2º requisição
          console.log(this.listAll = data['message']);
          this.totalOrder = this.listAll.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b['vlr_total'];
          }, 0).toFixed(2);
          console.log(this.totalOrder);
        });
      }//for
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="row-table-orders" *ngFor="let data of list | search: pp">
      <span>{{data.order_number | slice:0:6}}</span>
      <!-- it is shown just one line -->
      <span class="brown" *ngIf="data.status_order === 0">Pendente</span>
      <span class="green" *ngIf="data.status_order === 1">Aceito</span>
      <span class="red" *ngIf="data.status_order === 2">Cancelado</span>

      <span>{{data.name}}</span>

      <span>{{data.order_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
      <span>{{data.date_delivery | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
      <!-- it is shown just one line -->
      <span *ngIf="data.term_pay === 1">7 dias</span>
      <span *ngIf="data.term_pay === 2">15 dias</span>
      <span *ngIf="data.term_pay === 3">à vista</span>
      <span>{{totalOrder}}</span>

      <span>
        <button class="bt-edit" (click)="showingEdit(data)">
          <span>
            <svg style="width:18px;height:18px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path fill="#fff" d="M14.06,9L15,9.94L5.92,19H5V18.08L14.06,9M17.66,3C17.41,3 17.15,3.1 16.96,3.29L15.13,5.12L18.88,8.87L20.71,7.04C21.1,6.65 21.1,6 20.71,5.63L18.37,3.29C18.17,3.09 17.92,3 17.66,3M14.06,6.19L3,17.25V21H6.75L17.81,9.94L14.06,6.19Z" />
            </svg>
          </span>
          <span>editar</span>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

eu consegui pegar o total de cada pedido salvo no banco já com a variável totalOrder:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas no front só vem última e não estou conseguindo colocar em cada loop.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O 'totalOrder' é único e estás a gravar três resultados na mesma variável, o que faz com que só vejas o último resultado, porque escreves por cima dos outros resultados.

Troca o teu código por isto:

```
listOrders() {
this.service
    .getListOrders()
    .subscribe(data => { // 1º requisição

        this.list = data['message'];
        for (const numberOrders of this.list) {
            const numberOrder = numberOrders['order_number'];

            this.service
                .getListOrdersNumber(numberOrder)
                .subscribe(data => { // 2º requisição
                    const listAll = data['message'];
                    numberOrders['totalOrder'] = listAll.reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a + b['vlr_total'];
                    }, 0).toFixed(2);
            });
        }
});
```

}

E depois acedes ao valor usando o data['totalOrder']